# ¿Como mostrar correctamente una lista de elementos con foreach PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, array, mvc

Estoy trabajando una lista de productos que se mostraran de acuerdo al proyecto que esten relacionados, lo que significan que si hay dos o mas productos relacionados a un solo proyecto estos deberian de mostrarse en una tabla, aqui muestro el codigo y la vista:

Modelo donde hago la consulta:

```
class ModeloProductos{
/*=============================================
MOSTRAR PROMATE
=============================================*/

static public function mdlMostrarPromate($tabla, $item, $valor){

    if($item != null){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch();

    }else{

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll();

    }

    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;

}
}
```

Controlador:

```
class ControladorProductos{
/*=============================================
MOSTRAR PROMATE
=============================================*/

static public function ctrMostrarPromate($item, $valor){

    $tabla = "productos";

    $respuesta = ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarPromate($tabla, $item, $valor);
    //var_dump($respuesta);

    return $respuesta;

}
}
```

Y la vista es la siguiente, antes cabe mencionar que en `$valor` llamo desde el metodo `_GET` del url el id del proyecto:

```
<?php

        $item = "id_categoria";
        $valor = $_GET["idPromate"];

        $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarPromate($item, $valor);
        $listaproductos = array($productos);

        foreach ($listaproductos as $key => $value) {

          echo ' <tr>

                  <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
                  <td class="text-uppercase">'.$value["descripcion"].'</td>
                  <td class="text-uppercase">'.$value["tipoM"].'</td>
                  <td class="text-uppercase">'.$value["nomProyecto"].'</td>
                  <td class="text-uppercase">'.$value["stock"].'</td>
                  <td class="text-uppercase">'.$value["fecha"].''</td>
        }
```

Sin el array en la vista me muestra errores de `offset`, por lo que con el array trate de mandar a llamar a lista de productos que estan vinculados con `id` del proyecto a la vista, luego con un `foreach` trato de desglosar la infomacion en la vista, por lo que al principio pense que lo logre porque me mostro este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al realizar la consulta del modelo en mi **phpMyAdmin** me di cuenta que son dos productos que estan relacionados con el proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es ahi cuando me entro la duda del porque no me esta mostrando el otro resultado, me serviria de mucho su ayuda

Comment: Tu problema esta aquí return $stmt -> fetch(); cámbialo por $stmt ->fetchAll();

Comment: @leo_vilchis si lo agrego este me marca error diciendo que los campos que selecciono para ver son variables desconocidos.